# Reduce multiple tags to just one occurrence if there are no words between them with preg_replace

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I searched the web up and down couldn't find anything that would be a working solution.

Let's say I have multiple occurrence of `<u></u><font color="green"></font><i></i><div></div><big></big>`

like this:

`<u></u><font color="green"></font><i></i><div></div><big></big><u></u><font color="green"></font><i></i><div></div><big></big><u></u><font color="green"></font><i></i><div></div><big></big><u></u><font color="green"></font><i></i><div></div><big></big><u></u><font color="green"></font><i></i><div></div><big></big>`

I want it to be reduced to just one occurrence: `<u></u><font color="green"></font><i></i><div></div><big></big>`

The tags are not always the same. Basically I want multiple occurrences of tags that repeat again and again with no words between them to be reduced to just one occurrence. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Forget about regex use dom parser.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after. This is a bit of a hack, but it might get you started.

Use `(<.*>)\1+` as your search string, then replace with `$1`. You may need to run that a couple times.